# PHP - Pass each variable variable to new foreach

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

How to pass each variable variable to new foreach

I have this:

```
<?php
include_once('js/simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.homepage.com/');

foreach($html->find('figure a') as $eventLink)                  
    echo $urlVariable.$eventLink->href . "<br>";                        
?>
```

This works, result:

```
http://www.homepage.com/link1
http://www.homepage.com/link2
http://www.homepage.com/link3
http://www.homepage.com/link4
...
```

Desired: all the links as variable for a new foreach-function

```
<?php
include_once('js/simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.homepage.com/');

foreach($html->find('figure a') as $eventLink)                  
    echo $urlVariable.$eventLink->href . "<br>";                        



// Desired:

$newGrabbedLinks = .... // (should be ALL grabbed links equal to: echo $urlVariable.$eventLink->href )

foreach($newGrabbedLinks->find('.text') as $newTexts)   
        echo $newTexts->innertext;

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well I think what you're talking about is an array.

```
$links = array();
$html = file_get_html('http://www.homepage.com/');

foreach($html->find('figure a') as $eventLink)                  
    $links[] = $urlVariable.$eventLink->href;
```

Instead of echoing you're adding each value to a position in your array.

To add the array to a foreach function you would simply do

```
foreach($item in $links)
echo $item
```

Comment: I would like to have a variable that contains all the grabbed links, and then use this variable for a new foreach-function. The first echo was only for testing.

Comment: Well just add the array to the foreach function

Comment: Can you please add an example, how to add the array to the foreach function, to your answer? would be nice!

Comment: Thx, but it causes a crash. When i call " var_dump($links); " it shows me the array. I would pass this array as variables for finding ".text" content in each site from the url-array-"$links") and then echoing. (please have a look at my question above, ->Desired )

Comment: Alright take a printscreen and paste on imgur, the text is kinda hard to read

Comment: On the screen isn't any difference

Comment: Ok, well just add .find(".text") after $links in the foreach